# JavaFX How do I change Text node with a Button?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, javafx-8

I am building a Calculator. I have created a few classes so far. There is the IntegerButton which should display it's value on the Monitor when pressed.

```
package calculator.buttons;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class IntegerButton extends Button{
    int value;

    public IntegerButton(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.setText(Integer.toString(value));
        this.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
//                Handle the event as an integer
//                send event to monitor?
            }
        });
    }

}
```

However, I do not understand how to do this.

I am unable to reference the Monitor when I define handle(ActionEvent event) within the constructor of each button. In addition, I am completely lost with the concept of EventHandlers. Should my Monitor listen to events? Should my Button have its setOnAction called within the start(Stage primaryStage) method? I am at a total loss.

Here is my application's start method: package calculator;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author souten
 */
public class Calculator extends Application {

    public static final double MIN_HEIGHT = 525;
    public static final double MIN_WIDTH = 350;
    public static final double DEFAULT_GAP = 6;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
//        Window settings
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(MIN_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(MIN_WIDTH);

//        container is the base content node
//        - it contains 1 column and 3 rows
        GridPane container = new GridPane();
        container.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        column1.setPercentWidth(100);
        container.getColumnConstraints().add(column1);
        RowConstraints[] rows = new RowConstraints[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
            rows[i] = new RowConstraints();
        rows[0].setPercentHeight(40);
        rows[1].setPercentHeight(10);
        rows[2].setPercentHeight(50);
        container.getRowConstraints().addAll(rows);
        container.setHgap(0);
        container.setVgap(DEFAULT_GAP);

//        row 0: the monitor, outputs the calculations in hex, dec, oct, and bin

        Monitor m = new Monitor();
        container.add(m, 0, 0);

//        row 1: contains misc buttons i.e. bit-toggler, bit measurement, and memory buttons

//        row 2: the bottom row, keypadContainer contains all the buttons that create the calculation/function

        Keypad keypad = new Keypad();
        container.add(keypad, 0, 2);

//        Scene initialization
        Scene scene = new Scene(container, MIN_WIDTH, MIN_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add
          (Calculator.class.getResource("Calculator.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /** 
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Keypad class:

```
package calculator;

import calculator.buttons.IntegerButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Keypad extends GridPane{
    String[][] labels = {
        {"Lsh", "Rsh", "Or", "Xor", "Not", "And"},
           {"↑", "Mod", "CE", "C", "⌫", "÷"},
             {"A", "B", "7", "8", "9", "×"},     
             {"C", "D", "4", "5", "6", "−"},
             {"E", "F", "1", "2", "3", "+"}, 
             {"(", ")", "±", "0", ".", "="}
    };

    Button[][] buttons = new Button[6][6];

    public Keypad(){
        //        initialize buttons
        buttons[5][3] = new IntegerButton(0);
        buttons[4][2] = new IntegerButton(1);
        buttons[4][3] = new IntegerButton(2);
        buttons[4][4] = new IntegerButton(3);
        buttons[3][2] = new IntegerButton(4);
        buttons[3][3] = new IntegerButton(5);
        buttons[3][4] = new IntegerButton(6);
        buttons[2][2] = new IntegerButton(7);
        buttons[2][3] = new IntegerButton(8);
        buttons[2][4] = new IntegerButton(9);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if(buttons[i][j] != null)
                this.add(buttons[i][j], j, i);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

and my Monitor Class:

```
package calculator;

import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Monitor extends Text {


    public Monitor() {
        this.setText("Hello World!");
//      this.addListener?
    }
}
```

Basically I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to connect these nodes via events. How do?

Comment: Why are you using a monitor?

Comment: To display to the user what they are typing.

Comment: You need to get a reference to the `Monitor` instance to the `IntegerButton`s. You should probably pass it to the constructor. However I don't really see the purpose of creating new classes for every node used in your program especially since they do not even contain a single method each....

Comment: Thanks fabian. I don't see the purpose either. I am really just out here swinging hoping that I develop something somewhat organized. I didn't want to have any of my classes be too fat. However, I base that goal on nothing. I have almost no idea what a well written javafx application looks like. This is my first.

My Calculator will have 30 buttons: 10 integers, a sign switch, open/close parentheses, decimal point, operators, variables, clear and clear equation, Mod, Lsh, Rsh,... it goes on. I figured I wouldn't define each one in the main method.

Comment: @BenSoutendijk take a look at some online tutorials and stuff then. A good book is “Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftmanship”

Comment: You could take a look at this simple [Calculator example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4344564).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very basic example that illustrates how a Button event would work in the context your trying to use it.

```
public class SimpleButtonApp extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    GridPane container = new GridPane();

    Label displayLabel = new Label();

    String[][] labels = {
            {"Lsh", "Rsh", "Or", "Xor", "Not", "And"},
               {"↑", "Mod", "CE", "C", "⌫", "÷"},
                 {"A", "B", "7", "8", "9", "×"},     
                 {"C", "D", "4", "5", "6", "−"},
                 {"E", "F", "1", "2", "3", "+"}, 
                 {"(", ")", "±", "0", ".", "="}};

    for(int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < labels[i].length; j++) {
            String label = labels[i][j];

            Button button = new Button(label);
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    displayLabel.setText(displayLabel.getText() + label);
                }
            });
            container.add(button, i, j);
        }
    }

    container.getChildren().addAll(button, displayLabel);
    Scene scene = new Scene(container, 300, 100);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Some design hints for making a calculator:

1) A basic JavaFX Label should work for displaying the numbers

2) You don't need an IntegerButton class. A button is just a button.

3) Your event handlers should be defined in a place where you have access to both the Buttons and the Label.

Comment: I already understand how to do all this in one method. But how do I avoid having one huge method with like 30 buttons?

Comment: Then you will need a reference to your Display that you can get from your IntegerButton, either by passing it into the constructor as an argument or making a static getter on your Calculator class.

Comment: Or you could create your buttons & button events dynamically by looping through your Labels

Comment: I updated my answer to illustrate how the loop could look

Comment: I like the idea of a getter for my Calculator class. And since I have no real life work experience as a java programmer, would having 20 different subclasses of button be a headache for those who might look at my code later? I figured I would try to organize the program through its classes so that if someone wanted to add functionality to one type of button on the calculator they wouldn't have to sift through many lines of code.

Comment: From a Design perspective, I would say that 20 different subclasses of button where the only difference is the onActionEvent is bad design. I would also say that static getters for your components is also bad design. JavaFX provides the ability to add eventHandlers very easily without the need for extending classes. I know your against having 30 of these added in one place but I imagine you can dynamically create some (like for the numbers) and specifically create others (for the equals button and other function buttons. That might create a happy medium between readability and good design.

Comment: I think that answers my question then. I tend to agree, now that you have explained it, that some of my approach suffered from bad design. Whatever questions I had written above were predicated on a poor design evidenced by that fact that JavaFX doesn't work that way haha. Thanks.